# Spring Framework HandleInterceptor not parsing x-www-urlencoded body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have an API that use x-www-urlencoded as it's body. before entering the API, i have implement HandlerInterceptor to check header variables. my API is one of URLs that do not need to intercepted with HandlerInterceptor.. in the API, the x-www-urlencoded body is missing.. is there anything wrong with my code?

here is my code :

ServiceInterceptor.java

```
public class ServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String key = request.getHeader("Key");
    String timestamp = request.getHeader("Timestamp");
    String signature = request.getHeader("Signature");
    String apiMethod = request.getMethod();
    String jsonIn = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
    String url = request.getRequestURI().replace(request.getContextPath(), "");

    if (url.equals("/get-token")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        model.mdlErrorSchema mdlAPIStatus = AuthorizationAdapter.CheckAuthorization(authorization, key, timestamp, signature, response, jsonIn, apiMethod, url);

        if (mdlAPIStatus.error_code.equals("ERR-00-000")) {
        return true; // continue processing
        } else {
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(mdlAPIStatus));
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(400);
        return false;
        }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is my code for the API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-token", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public @ResponseBody model.mdlAPIObjectResult GetToken(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization, @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType, @RequestParam(value = "grant_type", defaultValue = "") String grantType, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (!grantType.equals("client_credentials")) {
    mdlAPIResult.error_schema = ErrorAdapter.GetErrorSchema(ErrorStatus.ERR_99_003);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    return mdlAPIResult;
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read the body only once. You are reading it in  your interceptor and hence the controller cannot read it again. You need an additional filter, which allows to re-read the stream.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any way to include the body again when the request enter controller? i use HandlerInterceptor to check authorization so every API i created don't need any function to check authorization again

Comment: No. You can only do that in a filter, you need to wrap the request and make sure that when methods like `getReader`, `getInputStream` is called the content gets cached, so that it can be re-read.